# Conectividade entre 2 Raspberry pi através de Local Network

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Como poderei conetar dois raspberry pi através de uma rede local ethernet, por exemplo enviar um texto de um para o outro através da rede local de ethernet.

Comment: Acessa via `ssh`, tem essa possibilidade?

Comment: Tem a biblioteca padrão a partir do Python 3.4 (PEP 3156): [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) e o [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki). E dependendo do Sistema Operacional do Raspberry, há o módulo [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html): "This module provides access to the BSD socket interface. It is available on all modern Unix systems, Windows, Mac OS X, BeOS, OS/2, and probably additional platforms."